# Asp.Net SignalR second tab does not fire onConnected event

Tags: asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I just created a sample project with signalR. I am just trying to test managing multiple connection. Everything works as expected when I open the first browser and load the page. It is going to fire the OnConnected event on the hub. But when I open another browser or different tab and load the page, it doesn't fire OnConnected event anymore. It shows $.connection.hub.id though.

Here is the hub

```
[HubName("genie")]
public class Genie : Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hub
{
    private static ConnectionManager _manager = new ConnectionManager();

    [HubMethodName("AdminCommand")]
    public void AdminCommand(string command, string message = "")
    {
        var connetions = _manager.GetConnections();

        connetions.Remove(Context.ConnectionId);

        Clients.Clients(connetions).onAdminCommand(command, message);
    }

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        _manager.AddConnection(Context.ConnectionId);

        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        _manager.RemoveConnection(Context.ConnectionId);

        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }
}
```

And here is the javascript code:

```
var proxy = $.connection.genie;

        $.connection.hub.start()
                .done(function (state) {
                    console.log($.connection.hub.id);
                });

        proxy.on('onAdminCommand', function (command, message) {
            if (command == "HappyGenie") {
                $scope.goTo("happy/");
            } else if (command == "SadGenie") {
                $scope.goTo("sad/");
            } else if (command == "CustomAnnouncement") {
                dataService.setDataByKey("Announcement", message);
                $scope.goTo("customannouncement/");
            }
        });
```

I establish a connection with the generated proxy.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Which browser do you use? Browser does limit number of connections. Try for example also an other browser?

Comment: For the second connection I open different browser.